# Python incorrect indexing of pandas.core.frame.Dataframe / how to delete a comma on the end of each row of a csv file?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe, indexing

I am working with multiple csv data files of 25,000 rows and what is supposed to be 2 columns. These data files came from an oscilloscope I am using to take data measurements. The files look like this:

*Bad file*

```
TIME,CH1  
-2.500000e-01,2.00e-03,  
-2.499800e-01,2.00e-03,  
-2.499600e-01,0.00e+00,
```

I have code written to process the data I took using a previous oscilloscope, which works just fine. That data looks like:

*Good file*

```
TIME,CH1,CH1 Peak Detect  
-1.8720e-01,-0.001,-0.155  
-1.8712e-01,0.005,0.143  
-1.8705e-01,0.001,-0.151
```

and I was only using the data from the first 2 columns. The only difference I can see between the two data files, apart from the extra column, is that the one that I'm having trouble with has each row ending in a comma, whereas the other one does not.

To get the data from the files I have been using the following to access and work with the data in each column:

```
r0 = pandas.read_csv("BADFILE.csv")
t0 = r0["TIME"]
v0 = r0["CH1"]
```

where

```
type(r0): pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
type(t0): pandas.core.series.Series
```

When I look at r0 in the python environment of the *bad file*, it appears as

```
           TIME  CH1
-0.25000  0.008  NaN
-0.24998  0.000  NaN
-0.24996 -0.002  NaN
```

which I believe indicates a problem with the indexing, as the *good file* shows r0 as

```
         TIME    CH1  CH1 Peak Detect
0    -0.19200 -0.001           -0.021
1    -0.19192 -0.001            0.021
2    -0.19185 -0.001           -0.023
```

I'm not sure how to go about fixing this indexing issue. I have explored

- finding a way to delete the last character in the rows of the bad file (couldn't find one)
- renaming the axes and creating a new index (maybe promising, but I couldn't understand how to implement it)
- adding a comma to each file's title line (didn't work)

With my level of experience, I'm having trouble finding and applying solutions that would do these things, and make this data file into a form that I can use.

I found a shoddy workaround that involves manually saving each csv file as an Excel file and using pandas to import them as excel files. This results in the proper indexing I was getting from the older csv files. However, I frequently work with a large number of files, so this isn't the most practical solution.

If you have any ideas on how I can fix this issue, any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: If you were to iterate over every line of the CSV, you could remove the ending comma with `row[:-1]`, However this would need to be modified if not every row ends in a comma

Answer (score 2):

You can open the file and right-strip the lines of commas into an in-memory `StringIO` buffer:

```py
from io import StringIO

with open("test.csv", "r") as f, StringIO() as buff:
    for line in f:
        buff.write(line.strip().rstrip(',') + "\n")
    buff.seek(0)
    df = pd.read_csv(buff)
```

Result:

```
      TIME    CH1
0 -0.25000  0.002
1 -0.24998  0.002
2 -0.24996  0.000
```

## Edit: Untested Python 2 version:

```py
from io import BytesIO

with open("test.csv", "r") as f, BytesIO() as buff:
    for line in f:
        buff.write(bytes(line.strip().rstrip(',') + "\n"))
    buff.seek(0)
    df = pd.read_csv(buff)
```

Comment: Thanks for the input! When I try it, I get "unicode argument expected, got 'str' " as an error on the line that says " buff.write(line.strip().rstrip(',') + "\n")". Any thoughts on that?

Comment: @KatherineW Are you using Python 2?

Comment: Yes, I believe I'm using python 2.7. Are you using the newer version?

Comment: @KatherineW I’m not PMende, but is there any particular reason you’re using Python 2 (legacy codebase, specialized libraries...) ?

Comment: @KatherineW If you switch to Python 3, it should work, If you're locked into using Python 2, you'll need to use another solution using `BytesIO`. I've added my best guess at a Python 2 solution in an edit above, but I haven't used Python 2 in years. I'd strongly recommend moving to Python 3 if you can. If my solution doesn't work, you may try debugging it yourself, then asking another question?